# getting error while creating unmanaged node groups using eksctl in eks

Tags: amazon-eks, unmanaged, eksctl

Anyone please help ,I'm getting this error "Error: couldn't create cluster provider from options: nodeGroups[0].overrideBootstrapCommand is required when using a custom AMI (nodeGroups[0].ami)"
while creating unmanaged node groups using eksctl command

eksctl create nodegroup --config-file=nodegroup.yml

and the node group.yml file is below and the same file is used to create eks clusters before and worked in deifferent env but now in prod getting above error

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: cluster-name
  region: ap-south-1

nodeGroups:
- name: worker-public-xlarge-general-v2
  instanceType: t2.xlarge
  desiredCapacity: 0
  minSize: 0
  maxSize: 10
  privateNetworking: false
  ami: auto
  labels:
    project: general
  tags:
    k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/project: general
    project: general
  ssh:
    publicKeyName: prod-cluster-name-key
  iam:
    attachPolicyARNs:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
      - arn:aws:iam::966902025223:policy/staging1-substrate-security-group-substrate-kube-allocate-eip
    withAddonPolicies:
      autoScaler: true
      certManager: true
      cloudWatch: true
      ebs: true
      efs: true
      imageBuilder: true
  securityGroups:
    attachIDs:
      # security group which holds exposed ports required by substrate
      - sg-0eb7b121e94dca857
      - sg-0de4913218a071673

- name: worker-public-xlarge-example-v2
  instanceType: t2.xlarge
  desiredCapacity: 0
  minSize: 0
  maxSize: 10
  privateNetworking: false
  ami: auto
  labels:
    project: example
  tags:
    k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/project: example
    project: example
  ssh:
    publicKeyName: prod-cluster-name-key
  iam:
    attachPolicyARNs:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
      - arn:aws:iam::966902025223:policy/staging1-substrate-security-group-substrate-kube-allocate-eip
    withAddonPolicies:
      autoScaler: true
      certManager: true
      cloudWatch: true
      ebs: true
      efs: true
      imageBuilder: true
  securityGroups:
    attachIDs:
      # security group which holds exposed ports required by substrate
      - sg-0eb7b121e94dca857
      - sg-0de4913218a071673
```

Answer (score 1):

`...nodeGroups[0].overrideBootstrapCommand is required when using a custom AMI (nodeGroups[0].ami)`

This is a [breaking change](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/3563) starting eksctl version 0.90.0. In your spec, the error is due to `ami: auto`, comment out these lines will do. It doesn't do anything to your spec anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried this but didn't work for me. Then after comparing with the previous deployment, the problem is with the kubectl version that I used and I reinstalled with version 0.75 to make it work.